# print_r() function shows values, but I can't access them for conditionals

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

Ok, I'm confused.  I am trying to learn how to upload an image file in PHP.

```
<form name="add_form" action="submit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in the submit.php file:

```
print_r($_FILES);
    if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])){
        echo "empty";
    }else{
        echo "not empty";
    }
```

print_r($_FILES); shows me this:

```
Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => van Gogh - GalleryPlayer.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbYjG7m [error] => 0 [size] => 1437795 ) )
```

But when I run if/else using (empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) it always echos "empty".  How can it be empty if it is in the print_r($_FILES) array?

My ultimate goal here is to check if the user has uploaded an image file (it's part of a larger form).  If they do, use it.  If not, use a default image.  So i'm just trying to test for the existence of the form field.  Make sense?

Thanks for any insight you may be able to provide.

Cheers!

Comment: You need to use the `name` attribute to access the file `if($_FILES['image']['name'] == "") echo "empty";`

Comment: Your `print_r()` output suggests you should use `empty($_FILES['image']['name'])` rather than `['file']['name']`

Comment: Tried this: `if(empty($_FILES['image']['type']))` and also `if($_FILES['image']['name;] == "")`.  Both fall into the first condition "empty".  Seems like all the variations I try, they all come back empty.

Comment: Just tried this too: `if(!file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))`.  Still comes back empty.

Answer (score -1):

$_FILES['image']['name'] is ok. try again.Then similar access to other fields

Comment: No it isn't "ok". It's not the right array name.

Comment: I test my local is correct, if wrong tell me position, brother